# How to launch artery example without graphical user interface

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have a question about artery (the veins extension):

If you launch the example with the command
`cmake --build build --target run_example` 
the framework will launch omnet++ for graphical debugging.

Is it possible to run this example without a graphical user interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the GUI is started or not depends on how you have [configured](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A24%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C191.764%2Cnull%5D) OMNeT++.
Configuring it with **Tkenv** or **Qtenv** starts the GUI and configuring it with 
**Cmdenv** does not.
If you want to start batched simulation runs for parameter analysis then this is only possible from the command line version.

You can [reconfigure](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A27%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C293.976%2Cnull%5D) OMNeT++ by setting the parameters **WITH_TKENV** and **WITH_QTENV** in the **configure.user** file to **no** and running `./configure` followed by `make cleanall` and `make`.

When using the command line, selecting the scenario to run can be done by going
to your build directory (probably build/) executing `ccmake .` and setting parameter **RUN_FLAGS** to `-c <config_name>` (e.g. -c My_First_Config).